# How to make a jade page compatible in IE 11

Tags: internet-explorer

I am  working on a project and i am having a problem with IE11, i mean in Chrome or Mozilla display correctly, but in Internet explorer distorts
how can i fix it ?

Here is my code in jade

```
link(href='./../fingrammotnost.css', rel='stylesheet')
.finfsafon.fin-fsa
  .page
    .page-main
      .header.headershadow(style="background-color:#1C9CD8 !important;color:#F5F7FB !important;")
        .row.mx-0
            .col-lg-6.col-md-6.col-sm-6.text-align-right
              .d-flex.order-md
                a.header-brand(ui-sref='home')
                  img.header-brand-img(src='/assets/images/gerb.png')
                span.ml-auto
                  span.text-default(style='font-size:15px;color:#F5F7FB !important;')
                    | {{'Государственная Служба Регулирования и Надзора за Финансовым Рынком при Правительстве Кыргызской Республики' | translate}}
                button.navbar-toggler(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.multi-collapse', aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent navbarSupportedContent2', aria-expanded='false', aria-label='Toggle navigation')
                  span.navbar-toggler-icon
            .col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-6.col-xs-12.text-align-right
              .d-flex.order-md
                span.ml-auto(style='font-size:10px')
                  span.text-default(style='color:#F5F7FB !important;') +996(312)555 555555, fingramotnost@fsa.kg
                  br
                  span.text-default(style='color:#F5F7FB !important;')  Кыргызская Республика, 720040, г. Бишкек, пр. Чуй, 114
                  ul.nav.border-0.flex-column.flex-lg-row
                    li.margin-header-li
                      a.nav-link(ui-sref='fingrammotnost' , style='font-size:13px; color:#F5F7FB !important;')
                        |  {{'ФИНАНСОВАЯ ГРАМОТНОСТЬ'|translate}}
                    li.margin-header-li
                      span(style='color:#F5F7FB !important;') |
                    li.margin-header-li
                      a.nav-link(ui-sref='form' , style='font-size:13px; color:#F5F7FB !important;')
                        |  {{fingramdetail.parent_menu[0].name | translate }}
            .col-lg-3.col-md-3.col-sm-12.col-xs-12.text-align-left
              span.ml-auto
                ul.nav.nav-tabs.border-0.flex-column.flex-lg-row
                  li.margin-header-li
                    a.nav-link(ng-click="fsa.changeLanguage('kg')", style='font-size:13px')
                      em {{'Кыргызча'|translate}}
                  li.margin-header-li
                    a.nav-link(ng-click="fsa.changeLanguage('ru')", style='font-size:13px')
                      em {{'на Русском'|translate}}
                  li.margin-header-li
                    a.nav-link(ng-click="fsa.changeLanguage('en')", style='font-size:13px')
                      em {{'in English'|translate}}
                form.margin-header-form(action='')
                  .input-group
                    input.form-control(type='text', placeholder="{{'Поиск...'|translate}}", name='s')
                    .input-group-append
                      button.btn.btn-secondary(type='submit')
                        i.fa.fa-search
      .row.mx-0.bg-white.p-2.shadow
        .col
          #navbarSupportedContent2.collapse.navbar-collapse.multi-collapse
            ul.navbar-nav.d-flex.flex-md-row.justify-content-around.w-100
              li.nav-item.d-flex.flex-grow-1.active(ng-repeat="item in fingramdetail.filteredmenus")
                button.btn.btn-lg.btn-block.btn-outline-primary(ui-sref='findetail({menu_id:"{{fingramdetail.menu_id}}", id:"{{item._id}}"})' ui-sref-active="active" active="isActive" ng-init="isActive=false" data-toggle='collapse', data-target='.multi-collapse', aria-controls='navbarSupportedContent navbarSupportedContent2', aria-expanded='false', aria-label='Toggle navigation')
                  | {{ item.name }}
    .row.pt-3.mx-0(style="min-height:300px;")
      div(ui-view='itemDetails')
  .ed_footer_wrapper
    .ed_footer_top
      .container
        .row
          .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-12
            .widget.text-widget
              p
                | {{ 'ГОСУДАРСТВЕННАЯ СЛУЖБА РЕГУЛИРОВАНИЯ И НАДЗОРА ЗА ФИНАНСОВЫМ РЫНКОМ ПРИ ПРАВИТЕЛЬСТВЕ КЫРГЫЗСКОЙ РЕСПУБЛИКИ ГОСФИННАДЗОР' | translate}}
              .ed_sociallink
                ul
                  li
                    a(href='#', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='bottom', title='Dribble')
                      i.fa.fa-dribbble
                  li
                    a(href='#', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='bottom', title='Retro')
                      i.fa.fa-camera-retro
                  li
                    a(href='#', data-toggle='tooltip', data-placement='bottom', title='Facebook')
                      i.fa.fa-facebook-official
          .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-12
            .widget.text-widget
              p
                i.fa.fa-phone
                |  {{ 'По вопросам работы сайта' | translate}}
                br
                |  {{ 'обращаться по телефону:' | translate}}
                br
                |                                 (+996 312) 96-13-10
              p
                i.fa.fa-envelope-o
                a(href='#') E-mail:fsa@fsa.kg
          .col-lg-4.col-md-4.col-sm-12
            .widget.text-widget
              p
                | {{ 'При использовании материалов размещенных на сайте активная ссылка на Финнадзор' | translate}}
                strong
                  a(href='index.html') (http://www.fsa.kg)
                |  {{ 'обязательна' | translate}}
              p
                i.fa.fa-safari
                | {{ 'Наш адрес: Кыргызская Республика,' | translate}}
                br
                |                                 720040,
                br
                |                                 {{ 'г.Бишкек, пр.Чуй,114' | translate}}
```

and above u can see a css file 
I have been struggling to fix it for 2 hours and i have no idea where to start
any helps please, i will really appreciate it

[In chrome it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMaPv.png)

[In IE 11 it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp2CJ.png)

Comment: Can you please show us what output you are getting in other browsers and what output you are getting in IE? It can help us to get the idea about the issue.

Comment: sure, in chrome it looks like

Comment: Based on my search, it looks like there are some CSS files for IE and you need to add references to those files like you can see in this link. https://codepen.io/timjgleeson/pen/oHlLf Still I am not sure about it so you can try to confirm the same from JADE support.